# DOMPDF - Can't pass variable from controller to blade

Tags: laravel, dompdf

I am trying to pass variable to blade and from some reason I can't. Not sure what I am doing wrong. This is my code.

This is my controller:

```
public function printPdf(){

  $data = [
    'title' => 'my title',
    'heading' => 'Hello from 99Points.info',
    'content' => 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industrys standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.'        
  ];
          
  $pdf = PDF::loadView('prints.main', $data);  
  return $pdf->stream('print.pdf',array("Attachment" => false));
}
```

This is my blade:

```
<head>

<title>{{ $title }}</title>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>{{ $heading}}</h1>



<div>


<p>{{$content}}</p>



</div>

</body>
```

And this is how pdf looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WUq1.png)

It see data as for example $title instead of 'my title'.

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the filename of the blade view?

Comment: Which lib are you using?

Comment: I just fixed that. Thanks a lot

Comment: you may remove the question as it does not help anyone